# MySQL keep a static view always in cache

Tags: mysql, caching

In my architecture, I have a big single table that:

- is **not** normally updated and can be considered as "read only"
- contains more than 2 millions of records
- is shared in several database (one for each of mt customer)

I put this table in a separate database and I created a view on it, in each single database.

Now, this configuration is slowing down the system. 
My idea is to "freeze" this view in a cache, but I cannot find the way to do it

Am I in the right way? Do you have some suggestion on how to maximize this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching in MySQL will not help because MySQL's [query cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) holds the results of queries, not individual tables that can be used in a query.

Depending on the size of your table and the available physical memory of your  server, you can add a [memory table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html) that has exactly the same structure as your big config table.

Whenever the MySQL server is restarted or the base config table is changed, you have to run a script that populates the memory table (in case of changes, just updates it). In your queries you can reference the memory table directly, not via a view.

However, there are quite a few restrictions on the memory table, so I'm not sure that this would be the right approach in your case.

Generally, table partitioning, creating appropriate indexes, and tuning MySQL configuration can significantly boost the performance of your database.

The slow queries must be assessed one by one using the `explain` statement, whereas the settings must be assessed by a knowledgeable MySQL DBA.